# Lodash String + Array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm learning lodash and looked over the massive doc and kind of exhausted looking for solution for this:

```
const r = 'ABCD';
const s = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
```

and I would like the final return value to be:

```
['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4']
```

My main concern is with performance. It has to be fast! What I have takes around 2500-3000ms for a list of ~56k.

Update:
What I did was:

```
[`${r[0]}${s[0]}`, `${r[1]}${s[1]}`, `${r[2]}${s[2]}`, `${r[3]}${s[3]}`]
```

Thanks for the suggestions. I tried _.map and native map and I'm kind of amazed at how much slower they are...

String template took 2.5s

lodash mapping r took 4.5s

lodash mapping s took 13s

native mapping r took 5s

native mapping s took 15s

I really wish I could drop it down to 1s..

Comment: `var result = _.map(r, (e, i) => e+s[i])`

Comment: Javascript is as fast as the browser and the computer capabilities of the client that is execute that code can be. If you need a fast proccessing with no differences to your clients, use your server, with a single AJAX request you can send all the details to server, proccess them on server, and return to client the result faster than proccess in client.

Comment: However, since you don't provide your code (that takes 3 seconds to finish) we can't help you better. Sorry.

Comment: @cocacrave - you deleted your most recent question too soon - I think I've got a solution!!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the native method [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for it.

```js
var r = 'ABCD',
    s = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    mapped = s.map((a, i) => r[i] + a);

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: @Tushar, not now anymore. it was only rhetoric.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer native js technique.

```
var r = 'ABCD',
    s = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
var mapped = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i<s.length; i++) {
  mapped.push('' + r[i] + s[i]);
}
console.log(mapped);
```

or you can use the js map function.

```
var r = 'ABCD',
    s = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    mapped = s.map((a, i) => r[i] + a);

console.log(mapped);
```